# $(window).resize(); not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want on set of functionality to be used on screen sizes larger than 768px and another set to be used on everything smaller than that. I need the `.resize()` so I can know when a user is turning their tablet or phone between landscape and portrait views.

The code on the inside of the `.resize()` event works fine if i refresh the page but it's as if the event isn't being triggered. Any thoughts?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function mobileFilterMenu(){
        var screenTest = $(window).width();
        if (screenTest >= 769){
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    elementOffset = $('.inventory-search > .col-md-9').offset().top,
                    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
                if(distance <= 0){
                    $('.filter-form').css('top', Math.abs(distance));
                }else{
                    $('.filter-form').css('top', 0);
                }
            });
        }else{
            var vHeight = $(window).height() - $('#switch').height() - $('#primary-menu-toggle').height();
            $('.filter-form').css('height', vHeight + 'px');
            vTextHeight = vHeight - 20;
            $('.wpv-filter-form').css('height', vTextHeight + 'px');
            objNegHeight = (vHeight * -1) + 50;
            $('.filter-form').css('top', objNegHeight + 'px');

            var i;
            $('#switch').click(function(){
                if (i === 0){
                    $('.filter-form').css('top', objNegHeight + 'px');
                    i++;
                }else{
                    $('.filter-form').css('top', '50px');
                    i = 0;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    mobileFilterMenu();
    $(window).resize(mobileFilterMenu());
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong! [this is what responsive design `media queries` take care of without buggy javascript.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en#apply-media-queries-based-on-viewport-size)!

Comment: `mobileFilterMenu()` CALLS the function. You want to PASS it. `$(window).on('resize',mobileFilterMenu);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this part of your code. This should fix your problem.

```
$(window).resize(mobileFilterMenu);
```

Instead of passing ***mobileFilterMenu()***, pass this ***mobileFilterMenu***

The parameter inside the ***$window.resize*** should have a ***function*** not a ***function call***.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `media queries` to apply `CSS` based on viewport dimensions not code!

> Media queries enable us to create a responsive experience, where
>   specific styles are applied to small screens, large screens and
>   anywhere in between. The media query syntax allows for the creation of
>   rules that can be applied depending on device characteristics.

```
@media (query) {
  /* CSS Rules used when query matches */
}
```

> While there are several different items we can query on, the ones used
>   most often for responsive web design are min-width, max-width,
>   min-height and max-height.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="max-640px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 640px)" href="min-640px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: landscape)" href="landscape.css">
<style>
  @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
      color: fuchsia;
    }

    .desc:after {
      content:" In fact, it's between 500px and 600px wide.";
    }
  }
</style>
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en#apply-media-queries-based-on-viewport-size